# Schema.org: "The property Organization/aggregateRating is not recognized by Google for an object of type Organization"

Tags: schema.org, microdata, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

Googles Structured Data Test Tool gives errors on my Schema.org implementation since some weeks:

> The property Organization/aggregateRating is not recognized by Google
>   for an object of type Organization.

What is wrong here?

The HTML looks like so:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Organization">
<section class="entry-header" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating"> 
<span itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness"> <h2 itemprop="name">BUSINESS NAME</h2> </span> 
 <span itemprop="ratingValue">5,0</span> </span> <span class="reviews"> <span class="count" itemprop="reviewCount">4</span>

.... other things here ....

</section>
</div>
```

What is missing here? What do I wrong?

Comment: There are mixed data vocabularies - try replacing the value of the top-level `itemtype` attribute with `http://schema.org/Organization`.

Comment: When testing your code, I don’t get the error you quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using two different vocabularies:

- The [`Organization` type](http://data-vocabulary.org/Organization) from **Data-Vocabulary.org**
- The [`AggregateRating` type](http://schema.org/AggregateRating) and the [`LocalBusiness` type](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness) from **Schema.org**

While using types from different vocabularies is allowed, you probably intended to use Schema.org instead of Data-Vocabulary.org, because the [`aggregateRating` property](http://schema.org/aggregateRating) is defined for [Schema.org’s `Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization), but not for Data-Vocabulary.org’s `Organization`.

So instead of

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Organization">
```

it would be

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
       <span itemprop="ratingValue">4</span>
       <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span>
       <span itemprop="reviewCount">2</span>
    </div>
```

try this markup.

Answer (score 0):

```
div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemtype="https://schema.org/AggregateRating" itemscope>
    <meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="Total Review Count i.e. 567" />
    <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="Rating Value i.e. 4.7" />
  </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).